# transition between expanding elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have another question.

I hope it does not count as dumb question again. most beginner questions seem to been seen as dumb.

Anyway I am trying to have the transition between clicking cards more smooth.

Currently you can click on a card and it expands down and it is smooth when you click on the same card, but if you click on one card then a diferent one it is not smoth expanding the elements.
Mostly when the cards are next to each other in full screen

```js
var $cell = $(".card");

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find(".js-expander").click(function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest(".card");

  if ($thisCell.hasClass("is-collapsed")) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
    //$cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');

    $thisCell.removeClass("is-collapsed").addClass("is-expanded");

    // if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass("is-inactive")) {
    //   //do nothing
    // } else {
    //   //$cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    // }
  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-inactive");
  }
});

$cell.find(".card__expander").click(function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
//close card when click on cross
$cell.find(".js-collapser").click(function () {
  var $thisCell = $(this).closest(".card");

  $thisCell.removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-inactive");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  color: #333a45;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.card__expander {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "\f115";
}
.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }

  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }

  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 4) {
    clear: left;
  }

  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(2n + 2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }

  .card:nth-of-type(2n + 3) {
    clear: left;
  }

  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 
-------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #fff;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
/*
.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25em 0.25em 0.4em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -moz-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -ms-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -o-transform: translatex(-400px);
  transform: translatex(-400px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before,
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappeer">
  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" id="pop1btn" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not a dumb question, but I can't reproduce the issue. When I view your sample full screen the transitions look smooth enough. What isn't smooth?

Comment: Well when you first click on a card it "slides down" when you click that same card it "slides up" but if you click a different card when one is open it kind of just flashes to the next open one, i would like it to be able to "slide up" then slide the new one down.

Answer (score 0):

A little timeout value will help.
First I check to see if there are any expanded and set a timeout MS number:
`let timeout = $('.is-expanded').length > 0 ? 200 : 0`
If there is something expanded, the timeout will be 200 miliseconds.

Then we set the expanding element in a timeout, which will be zero if there is nothing currently expanded:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      $thisCell.removeClass("is-collapsed").addClass("is-expanded");
    }, timeout)
```

You can adjust the timeout value

```js
var $cell = $(".card");

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find(".js-expander").click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest(".card");

  if ($thisCell.hasClass("is-collapsed")) {
    let timeout = $('.is-expanded').length > 0 ? 200 : 0
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
    //$cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');

    setTimeout(() => {
      $thisCell.removeClass("is-collapsed").addClass("is-expanded");
    }, timeout)

    // if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass("is-inactive")) {
    //   //do nothing
    // } else {
    //   //$cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    // }
  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-inactive");
  }
});

$cell.find(".card__expander").click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
//close card when click on cross
$cell.find(".js-collapser").click(function() {
  var $thisCell = $(this).closest(".card");

  $thisCell.removeClass("is-expanded").addClass("is-collapsed");
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass("is-inactive");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  color: #333a45;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.card__inner:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}

.card__expander {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "\f115";
}

.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n + 4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(2n + 2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2n + 3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------------------------------- 
-------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #fff;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}


/*
.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25em 0.25em 0.4em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -moz-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -ms-transform: translatex(-400px);
  -o-transform: translatex(-400px);
  transform: translatex(-400px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before,
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}

.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappeer">
  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" id="pop1btn" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```